# building multiple indexes with hibernate search

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, hibernate-search

I'm working on full-text-search functionality within a spring MVC project. The search function has to be able to search for multiple entities (which can selected by the user). I created a RequestMapping to the following function which allows me to build indexes for the @Indexed classes in my model.

```
public void bouwIndex(HttpServletResponse response) throws InterruptedException {
    OutputWriter output = new HttpResponseOutputWriter(response);
    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = org.hibernate.search.jpa.Search.getFullTextEntityManager(em);
    fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    output.writeLn("Lucene index built!");
}
```

Let's say I have two classes (Profielwerkstuk and Begrip) which I have annotated and want to have indexed. When add the @Indexed annotation to the Profielwerkstuk class but not to the Begrip class and call the index-builder URL, Profielwerkstuk gets indexed correctly and within reasonable time (20 seconds or so) and searching Profielwerkstukken on this index works perfectly fine. Similarly, when the @Indexed annotation is added to the Begrip class but not to the Profielwerkstuk class, the index for Begrip is also created correctly and within reasonable time (10 seconds or so).

Problems arise when I add the @Indexed class to both the Profielwerkstuk class and the Begrip class and try to built the indexes, now creating the indexes ran for over 10 hours without completing (I terminated it after 10 hours). I would expect that the task to be completed by the indexer would be the same as first building the Profielwerkstuk index and then building the Begrip index, which are both tested to complete within reasonable time. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing my indexer to take so long?

**Edit:**
On request the relevant, annotated parts of Profielwerkstuk and Begrip are added.

Begrip:

```
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = DutchAnalyzer.class)
public class Begrip {

    @Field
    private String naam;

    @Lob
    @Field
    private String omschrijving;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "begrip")
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = { "onderwerp.naam" })
    private List<OnderwerpBegripRelatie> onderwerpen;

    @OneToOne(optional=true, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = { "content", "elementen.content" })
    private ContainerElement inhoud;
}
```

Profielwerkstuk:

```
@Indexed
@Analyzer(impl = DutchAnalyzer.class)
public class Profielwerkstuk {

    @Field
    private String titel;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = { "content", "elementen.content" })
    private ContainerElement inhoud;

    @Lob
    @Field
    private String bronvermelding;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="profielwerkstuk")
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = { "vraag", "toelichting", "eindtermen.keywords.keyword" })
    private List<Onderzoeksvraag> onderzoeksvragen = new ArrayList<Onderzoeksvraag>();
}
```

I can add to this that the class OnderwerpBegripRelatie as embedded in Begrip is not related to Profielwerkstuk, and Onderzoeksvraag in Profielwerkstuk is not related to Begrip. The ContainerElement part might also be of help in answering the question, as both Profielwerkstuk and Begrip have a ContainerElement field with @IndexedEmbedded.

ContainerElement:

```
public class ContainerElement extends Element {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="container", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @IndexedEmbedded(includePaths = { "content" })
    protected List<Element> elementen;
}
```

And its parent class Element:

```
public class Element {

    @Lob
    @Field
    private String content;
}
```

Comment: It sounds to me that your two classes have a bidirectional association and you run into a cycle of indexation : when you index A then it indexes B which indexes A and so on... Can you post the relevant parts of your classes ?

Comment: No there is no cycle as there is a limit, which is quite low since he's using explicit _includePaths_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be hitting [HSEARCH-598](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HSEARCH-598), you can find out by reducing drastically the number of threads used by the MassIndexer or putting a very large limit of connections in your connection pool. Also don't forget to configure your database to allow many connections.

If that's the case, please comment on the issue, we'll boost priority on it.. sorry I didn't solve it yet as any solution proposed so far has a bad impact on overall indexing time.

Comment: This indeed seemed to be the problem. I used the threadsForSubsequentFetching() and threadsToLoadObjects() as described in the MassIndexer documentation, and now building the index indeed completes! I'll also add it as a comment to the bug report.

Comment: Yesterday it seemed like the problem was solved, but now it appears to be still present. See the edits in the question.

Comment: What did you do exactly? You reduced the threads? Make sure you verify you have enough connections.